# How can I make and ASP action filter return a status code of 201?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this action filter:

```
public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

But my front-end code sees this in the same way that it sees a lost connection to the server.

How can I make it so that instead of returning a BadRequestObjectResult that I return a status code of 201 ?

Comment: `HTTP 201` is "Created' - are you sure that's the status code you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can throw an exception like this:

```
if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created));
}
```

This will immediately stop the request and return a 201 to the client.